# I want to set the background color for a text correctly using CSS. It does not react as I expect

Tags: html, css

I set a background color for a text but it got set to the whole line in front. I just want it to be set for the text.
This is what is happening-
[This is what is happening-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1rY9.png)

But I just want it to be the background of 'Something' and not the entire line.
Please help me.

Comment: attach your codebase what you have tried

Comment: Should we guess the code behind your image?

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` to get rid of the width

```css
p {
  background-color: green;
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the text in an inline element, such as a .

```
<h1><span>Something</span></h1>
```

And then apply the background color on the inline element.

```
h1 {
    text-align: center; 
}
h1 span { 
    background-color: green; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1><span  style=" background-color: coral;">The background-color Property</span></h1>

<p>The background color can be specified with a color name.</p>

</body>
</html>
```